# How to use Multiple Selection with Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

How can I link the transaction to the member, like link a transaction id to many member ids?

I have an activity to create new transaction, in that activity I enter the name of the transaction and have a button to insert. After I click on that button, I want to see the list of members.

Then I want to choose the members I want to link to the transaction. By clicking on every member, it should show me a tick or something next to the member I chose or it should set the clicked members in a different colour.

Then the transaction should be inserted with all the linked members I chose.

I did it like this for now, that I just make a new transaction, click on it, start a new activity with the chosen transaction, then in the toolbar I click on a button to start another activity where I should be able to choose the members I want to link with the transaction.

Is it possible to choose the members I want to link to the transaction directly with the new transaction activity? Or is it possible to make a new transaction and when I click on the button to save the new transaction, it inserts the record into the database and directly after insert, the activity where I choose the members to link to the transaction starts?

Also regarding my delete method: I have the method implemented in a onSwipe method. How can I do so that I can click on multiple transactions, they have a tick or a different colour, and delete them all at the same time?

I can click on a button (e.g. in the toolbar) to delete, then choose multiple members, click on a "confirm delete" button, let a confirmation screen appear (but not deleting yet), and after accepting the confirmation screen, delete them?

Class Transaction:

```
@Entity(tableName = "transaction_table")
public class Transaction {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "TransactionID")
private long id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "Transaction Name")
private String transactionName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "Transaction Balance")
private double balance;

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTransactionName() {
    return transactionName;
}

public void setTransactionName(String transactionName) {
    this.transactionName = transactionName;
}

public Transaction(String transactionName, double balance) {
    this.transactionName = transactionName;
    this.balance = balance;
}

}
```

Class Member:

```
@Entity(tableName = "member_table")
public class Member {


@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "MemberID")
private long id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "First Name")
private String firstname;

@ColumnInfo(name = "Surname")
private String surname;

@ColumnInfo(name = "Balance")
private double balance;

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Member(String firstname, String surname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.balance = 0;
}

}
```

Class Transaction Main Activity:

```
public class TransactionMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TransactionListAdapter.TransactionClickListener {

private TransactionViewModel mTransactionViewModel;
private List<Transaction> mTransaction;

public static final int NEW_TRANSACTION_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.transaction_activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_TransactionMainActivity);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.Transaction);
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab_TransactionMainActivity);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TransactionMainActivity.this, NewTransactionActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_TRANSACTION_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewCard_Transaction);
    final TransactionListAdapter adapter = new TransactionListAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mTransactionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TransactionViewModel.class);

    mTransactionViewModel.getAllTransactions().observe(this, new Observer<List<Transaction>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Transaction> transactions) {
            mTransaction = transactions;
            adapter.setTransaction(transactions);
        }
    });

    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(
            new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                    ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                @Override
                public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                      RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                                      RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                    Transaction myTransaction = adapter.getTransactionAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(TransactionMainActivity.this,
                            getString(R.string.TransactionDeleted) + " " +
                                    myTransaction.getTransactionName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    mTransactionViewModel.delete(myTransaction);
                }
            });
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.MainMenuToolbarSearch:

        case R.id.MainMenuToolbarAdd:

        case R.id.MainMenuToolbarDelete:

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == NEW_TRANSACTION_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(data.getStringExtra(NewTransactionActivity.EXTRA_REPLY), data.getDoubleExtra(NewTransactionActivity.EXTRA_REPLY2, -1));
        mTransactionViewModel.insert(transaction);
    } else

    {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.transaction_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Class New Transaction Activity:

```
public class NewTransactionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.transactionlistsql.REPLY";
public static final String EXTRA_REPLY2 = "com.example.android.transactionlistsql.REPLY2";

private EditText mEditTextTransaction;
private EditText mEditTextTransaction2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newtransaction_activity);
    mEditTextTransaction = findViewById(R.id.NewTransactionName);
    mEditTextTransaction2 = findViewById(R.id.NewTransactionBalance);
    mEditTextTransaction2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    mEditTextTransaction2.setText("0");
    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.NewTransactionButtonSave);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditTextTransaction.getText())){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.TransactionNameMissing, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditTextTransaction2.getText())){
                mEditTextTransaction2.setText("0");
            }
            else {                 
                String newtransactionname = mEditTextTransaction.getText().toString();
                double newtransactionbalance = (Double.parseDouble(mEditTextTransaction2.getText().toString()));
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, newtransactionname);
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY2, newtransactionbalance);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

My AsyncTask for insert method:

```
    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Transaction, Void, Void> {

    private TransactionDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    insertAsyncTask(TransactionDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Transaction... params) {
        mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The line marked as error is this one: mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);

Error:

```
07-11 03:10:49.003 16307-16508/com.example.mainbuchhaltung E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4

Process: com.example.mainbuchhaltung, PID: 16307

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)
#################################################################
Error Code : 787 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOEIGNKEY)
Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
    (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787))
#################################################################
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:915)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:50)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:64)
    at com.example.mainbuchhaltung.Transaction.TransactionDao_Impl.insert(TransactionDao_Impl.java:96)
    at com.example.mainbuchhaltung.Transaction.TransactionRepository$insertAsyncTask.doInBackground(TransactionRepository.java:64)
    at com.example.mainbuchhaltung.Transaction.TransactionRepository$insertAsyncTask.doInBackground(TransactionRepository.java:54)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a relation between Transaction and Member entity like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51208423/9293029)

Then once you get transaction data (TransactionName and Amount) then you have to pass data to MemberList activity like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325248/9293029)

Now in your MemberList screen once have done with your selection follow below process:
Suppose you have member ids in a string.

```
String memberIds = "12,18,25,27,30";
```

Now you have to create Transaction entity object with all member ids separated and insert it in the table of Transaction like below.

```
    String[] memberArray = memberIds.split(",", memberIds.length());
            for(String memberId : memberArray){
                // transactionName & transactionAmount which you received in the bundle from add transaction activity
                Transaction objTransaction = new Transaction(transactionName, transactionAmount); 
                objTransaction.setMemberId(Long.parseLong(memberId));
                // Insert data into your database
                mTransactionViewModel.insert(objTransaction);
            }
```

It will create a separate entry for each memberId in "transaction_table" table with one to one relationship.

You can fetch data of Transaction by executing query mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51208423/9293029)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One of the problems I face is that I don't have something implemented, which does the multiple selection. I only found examples of ListView Multiple Selection, but not for a RecyclerView. I also can't use the objTransaction.setMemberId, because it asks for a Long. Also, how can I do a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: I'm sorry if I bother you with my questions, I began with programming not a long time ago, so I don't have enough programming experiences yet.

Comment: @LordGash Check multiple item selection example of RecyclerView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369913/how-to-implement-multi-select-in-recyclerview). I updated my answer to parse String to Long. You have to write `objTransaction.setMemberId(Long.parseLong(memberId));`. If you get member id in int then no need to Parse you can directly set it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I tried to do all the things. I implemented the multiple selection. But I don't know if the method to pass the members works, because after I added the ForeignKey, it shows me an error with the insert.AsyncTask method. I edit my post and put the error in it. Can you please help me with this one?

Comment: @LordGash First of all, make sure you have MemberId exist in your member_table. If you try to insert member id into transaction_table which does not exist in member_table then it will give this type of error. [Read here for more info](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html). Whenever you made any changes in your database structure during implementation/development time, please uninstall existing app first then install a fresh one.

Comment: but member does exist in my Member.class. I put the code above. The error was shown in the AsyncTask insert line right? In my Dao, as my insert method,  I have this: @Insert
    void insert(Transaction transactions);. This is before the foreign key implementation. Do I have to change this Dao insert method after foreign key implementation? If yes, how do I change it?

Comment: You insert method is correct. Just make sure that before you call insert method, your memberId set in the Transaction object. If possible, can you please make a demo project of your issue and share a link of it? It will be easy and fast to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah sure, where should I upload the project?

Comment: You can upload it on https://github.com/ or you can upload it on your google drive and share the link of it.

Comment: Okay, wait a moment, gonna upload it to Google Drive.

Comment: @LordGash the problem is in `mTransactionViewModel.insert(transaction);` in your `TransactionMainActivity.java` file. In your transaction object, MemberId is not set and you are trying to insert it into database therefore it is giving `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` error. I resolved your error but one question is how you want to display data in Transaction list screen. [Check this screenshot.](https://imgur.com/a/Yr5LCBD)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174873/discussion-between-lordgash-and-viraj-patel).